# removing symbol only when they are next/prior to a word in python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I would like to remove colons(:) next/prior to words, but not remove the colons next/prior to numbers(e.g., in time). meaning, I don't want the colons in time to be removed, only the colons associated with words.

Example Input:

```
2018-05-21T00:00:00+02:00
00:00:00
00:00
:light at 07:15:0000

:occurence1
:occurence2

light: at 07:15:0000

occurence1:
occurence2:
```

Expected output: (with colons next/prior to words removed)

```
2018-05-21T00:00:00+02:00
00:00:00
00:00
light at 07:15:0000

occurence1
occurence2

light at 07:15:0000

occurence1
occurence2
```

I could match them with regex pattern: `([A-Za-z_]\w*:|:[A-Za-z_]\w*)`. but haven't been able to remove the colons, with `re.sub()`.

How do I do this with python3.8 with/without regex?

Comment: Did you try `re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Za-z]):|:(?=[A-Za-z])', '', text)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this expression doesn't account for occurences like `occurence2:`. so, i have modified to `r'(?<=[A-Za-z_]\w):|:(?=\w[A-Za-z])'`. thank you for your time and the comment. more: https://regex101.com/r/Z2Tmaz/2

Comment: Probably, `re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z_]\w*)(?<!T\d{2}):|(?<!\d):(?!\d+\b)', r'\1', text)` will also work. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YPdzgF/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part `[A-Za-z_]\w*:` the `\w` also matches digits resulting in matching too much. In the second pattern, you can omit the `\w*` at the end as it is optional and not necessary in the replacement.

You are also matching the whole part in stead of the parts without the `:`, and using the whole part with re.sub will result in removing everything that is matched.

You can use 2 separate groups where the first group can capture optional digits, match `:` without being followed by a digit and use the groups in the replacement.

```
([A-Za-z_]\d*):(?!\d)|:([A-Za-z_])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TJafX1/1)

```
import re

regex = r"([A-Za-z_]\d*):(?!\d)|:([A-Za-z_])"

s = ("2018-05-21T00:00:00+02:00\n"
     "00:00:00\n"
     "00:00\n"
     ":light at 07:15:0000\n\n"
     ":occurence1\n"
     ":occurence2\n\n"
     "light: at 07:15:0000\n\n"
     "occurence1:\n"
     "occurence2:")

result = re.sub(regex, r"\1\2", s)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
2018-05-21T00:00:00+02:00
00:00:00
00:00
light at 07:15:0000

occurence1
occurence2

light at 07:15:0000

occurence1
occurence2
```

A lookaround variant as commented by Wiktor Stribiżew with an extra alternation asserting a digit to the left and no digit to the right.

```
(?<=[A-Za-z]):|:(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=\d):(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gljP83/1)

Comment: both regular expressions doesn't work where it should works where it shouldn't. here's what has worked for me; `(?<=[A-Za-z_]\w):|:(?=\w[A-Za-z])` and more at https://regex101.com/r/Z2Tmaz/2

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala I works for the example data, that is the only thing I can work with.

Comment: it's fine @Thefourthbid, because the problem is now solved.